# How to call Service in controller in Service layer with repository pattern

Tags: laravel, service-layer

I'm learning about **Service layer with repository pattern** in Laravel. So, I have a question:

I have two services: `ProductService` and `PostService`. Both services have `getAll` function:

```php
class ProductService 
{
    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->productRepository->getAll();
    }
}

class PostService 
{
    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->postRepository->getAll();
    }
}
```

In `HomeController`, action `index`, I wanna show all posts and products. How should I code ?

**Option 1**. Call two services, then call getAll:

```php
class HomeController
{
    public function index(){
        $products = $this->productService->getAll();
        $posts = $this->postService->getAll();

        return view('index', compact('posts', 'products'));
    }
}
```

**Option 2**. Declare HomeService, then call:

```php
class HomeService 
{
    public function index()
    {
        return [
            'products'  => $this->productRepository->getAll(),
            'posts'     => $this->postRepository->getAll()
        ];
    }
}

----------

class HomeController
{
    public function index(){
        $data = $this->homeService->index();
        return view('index', $data);
    }
}
```

Pls help me! Thank you!